# How Can I create a kubernetes secret using secretproviderclass of the entire OBJECT? Not tied to a single key

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-secrets

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets
spec:
  provider: aws                           
  secretObjects:
  - data:
    - key: somekey   
      objectName: awssecretmanagersecretname 
    secretName: mysecretname
    type: Opaque
  parameters:                    
    region: us-east-1
    objects:  |
      - objectName: awssecretmanagersecretname
        objectType: secretsmanager
```

Now the above creates a new secret in kubernetes and puts everything from the awssecretmanager secret INTO a SINGLE key called "somekey". How can I transfer the awssecretmanager secret object directly into "mysecretname" as key value pairs? Thanks

To be clear I'm looking for something like

```
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: aws-secrets
spec:
  provider: aws                           
  secretObjects:
  - data:
    - objectName: awssecretmanagersecretname
    secretName: mysecretname
    type: Opaque
  parameters:                    
    region: us-east-1
    objects:  |
      - objectName: awssecretmanagersecretname
        objectType: secretsmanager
```

Without the key "somekey", is this possible? Thanks